# Installing laravel in the required directory. Installation command options

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php, optional-parameters

I decided to install laravel in D:\OpenServer\domains\myedica. Found the following install command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

As a result (see screenshot), the laravel folder was installed in the myedica folder. How to install laravel directly to the root of the myedica folder (one level higher than it is now)?

[image]

I want help with laravel install command options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel <application_name>
```

You must install your application to empty folder

So:

- rename past project folder
- create new laravel app
- move scripts from prev application

```
cd D:\OpenServer\domains\
ren "myedica" "myedica_past"
composer create-project laravel/laravel myedica
```

Then move what you need

- from `D:\OpenServer\domains\myedica_past`
- to `D:\OpenServer\domains\myedica`